# Getting area (%) of two intersecting polygons in Python

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, pandas

I am trying to calculate the area of two intersecting polygons in my GDB using Python (probably geopandas).

[image]

I have found solution using PostGIS:

```
SELECT layer.text,
       layer_2.text,
       sum(st_area(st_Intersection(layer.shape, layer_2.shape))/st_area(layer.shape)*100) as coverage 
FROM layer
LEFT OUTER JOIN layer_2 ON st_intersects(layer.shape, layer_2.shape)
GROUP BY layer.text, layer_2.text
ORDER BY layer.text;
```

result table:

```
| Layer | Layer_2 | coverage |
|-------|---------|----------|
| M1    | 1       | 48.86627 |
| M1    | 2       | 52.42329 |
| M2    | 1       | 22.5502  |
| M2    | 2       | 76.46014 |
| M3    | 3       | 13.24482 |
| M4    | 1       | 57.85429 |
| M4    | 2       | 12.05814 |
| M4    | 3       | 24.51523 |
| M5    |         |          |
```

This solution is allright, but I am trying to get the same result using Python.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Look at [Calculating polygon area within other polygon using GeoPandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/416411/2581)

Answer (score 2):

You can use spatial join (which is very fast) to find the polygons intersecting, calculate the intersection area and join to the input:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

df1 = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/layer1.shp') #I have a unique id column called id1...
df1['g1'] = df1.geometry #The geometry column is lost in the sjoin
df2 = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/layer2.shp') #.. and id2
df2['g2'] = df2.geometry 

#Spatial join the dataframe to then only intersect the intersecting geometries
inter = df1.sjoin(df2)
inter.columns
#Index(['id1', 'geometry', 'original_area', 'index_right', 'id2'], dtype='object')

def f(frame):
    """A function to calculate overlap percentage"""
    interpct = 100*frame.g1.intersection(frame.g2).area/frame.g1.area
    return interpct

inter['pct'] = inter.apply(f, axis=1)
#inter.columns
#Index(['id1', 'geometry', 'g1', 'index_right', 'id2', 'g2', 'pct'], dtype='object')

#Merge the intersect result and the input dataframe
result = pd.merge(inter, df1, on='id1',how='outer').set_geometry('geometry_y').rename_geometry('geometry')

result = result[['id1','id2','pct','geometry']]
result.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/result.shp')
```

[image]